# Can you run a regex on a register or the clipboard contents?

Tags: regular-expression, register, os-clipboard

I want to copy something to a register or more ideally the system clipboard and then run a search / replace regex on it the way that I do in the buffer...is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume you copied the following line to the register `+`:

```
Copied to clipboard.
```

Now you want to replace "clipboard" with "register" inside the register `+`:

```
:let @+=substitute(@+, 'clipboard', 'register', 'g')
```

The `@+` represents the register `+`, `@@` is the unnamed register, `@a` is register `a`,... . See `:help :let-@`.

And `substitute(...)` is processing a string (here from reg `+`) like  `:s/clipboard/register/g` would process the line in the file.